# DP/HDMI monitors show "no signal" - Debian 11

Tags: multi-monitor, gpu

This week I returned to my job after 2 week break and I discovered one important error. Any of my 3 monitors is not responding. All monitors keep displaying only "No signal".

I have tried multiple solutions, f.e. keep connected only one monitor (I have tried both DP and HDMI), which did not help, after that I have tried connecting all monitors to other PC and they were working without any issues (so there is not any problem with monitors itself or cables).

After that, I've tried restarting gdm3 service with command below:

> $ sudo service gdm3 restart

Which also did not solv anything, so last option was restarting whole PC:

> $ sudo reboot

Some important PC specs:

> inxi -Fx

CPU: Intel Core i7-3930K

GPU: Ellesmere [Radeon RX 470/480/570/570X/580/580X/590] (I'm not quite sure, which one is inside)

MB: Gigabyte X79-UD3

OS: Linux  6.0.0-0.deb11.6-amd64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Debian 6.0.12-1~bpo11+1 (2022-12-19) x86_64 GNU/Linux

What is interesting, some time ago I had similar issues on my home PC (Ubuntu 22.04, core i5, RTX 2060; PC was not able to connect to HDMI display, although second DP display was working normally). I'm using GPU driver directly from nVidia. After I updated drivers, this issue disappeared.

So, my question is, could be Radeon GPU dead (in that case, would PC even boot up?), or might it be some driver issue and updating it might resolve the problem?

I'd be more than happy for any advice.

Best wishes,
Ondrej.

Comment: please, use proper syntax formatting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yesterday I've solved it by first stopping gdm3 service with command

> $ sudo systemctl stop gdm3

After that, I again turned gdm3 service on with

> $ sudo systemctl restart gdm3.service

All three monitors are now working.